# Combining Kleisli using a set fold

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I'm using scala 2.11 and Scalaz 7.2.3 (latest).

I have trouble with combining Kleisli. I have two functions :

```
type A = ...
type B = ...
def set: Set[A]
def f: A => Kleisli[scalaz.effect.IO, B, Unit]

val result: Set[Kleisli[scalaz.effect.IO, B, Unit]] = set.map(f(_))
```

But I'm looking for a result more as a combination of Kleisli. In fact, my type should stay Kleisli[scalaz.effect.IO, B, Unit], under the same IO each effect piles up.

I tried stuff like folding for example :

```
set.fold(Kleisli.???)((acc, a) => acc andThen f(a))
```

but I can't find the right syntax, especially for the zero Kleisli.

Any help would be appreciated !

edit: clarified

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear. Do you want to execute `f2` for all the elements of a `Set[A]` ? And what has the `elements` to with the first part ?

Comment: Sorry about the clarity, I'll try to ellaborate. Yes, f needs to be executed for each elements of the Set[A].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `traverse` :

```
val result: Kleisli[IO, B, List[Unit]] = set.toList.traverse(f2)
```

We need to go from `Set` to `List` because there doesn't exist a `Traverse[Set]` (the type class which gives us the `traverse` function).

If you want `Kleisli[IO, B, Unit]` you can do `result.void` (which is analogous to `result.map(_ => ())`.

Comment: Awesome ! Learnt something new today ! I'm not exactly where I should be, but this traverse function is gonna be great =)

Comment: You can also go to `Kleisli[IO, B, Unit]` directly using `set.toList.traverse_(f2)`.

Comment: Allright I'm going to use this even though Unit and List[Unit] are identical. I guess my initial problem was my inability to express exactly what I wanted, which is: wrap in one IO operation the sequencing of this function on this list using as a parameter this B and return nothing.